# Using canvas or WebGL to pan and zoom many SVG images at high FPS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg, webgl

My application needs to draw hundreds - thousands of images on the screen, as well as some primitive shapes like circles and lines that connects them. The main concern of my app is that I will be able to pan and zoom very quickly with no lags at a high FPS - similar experience to a Google Maps like app.

Because I want my images to look sharp when zoomed, I created my icons using SVG so they are not pixelated after zoom.

My current implementation uses d3 and the DOM to display everything. It works fine but as the number of DOM nodes gets high the FPS drops, and zooming becomes laggy.

From what I understand my options are using a better renderer such as canvas or WebGL. My problem is that these renderers do not support svg scaling, so even if I draw my image with ctx.drawImage(), after zooming it looks bad.

I tried to look at some libraries like PIXI.js, three.js and such but the don't seem to offer that functionality.

How can I use a modern renderer while preserving my icons sharpness after zooming?

Comment: Modules d3-shape and d3-zoom of D3 v4 ship with good support for zooming and rendering to canvas. Like in most other cases providing a working demo to illustrate your problem would be a great help to get help! E.g. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b783fbb2e673561d214e09c7fb5cedee

Comment: Google maps relies on bandwidth. Most of the image content is loaded  as needed at a resolution to match the display and current zoom, additional layers are 2D mesh objects (similar to 3D mesh but without the z) generated in realtime (or static). Google has the advantage of huge data storage and can thus store all the content at the many resolutions required. To get the same you will need to do the same. There are plenty of apps that can convert SVG to what ever format  you want, including webGL ready 2D mesh objects, but meshes also need to match resolution to maintain frame rate.

Comment: "Distance Field" technique may be suitable for you. There is several implementation in webgl out there.  http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf